# SQL Server insert trigger not firing using EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, triggers

I have this insert trigger which handles duplicate key insert attempts:

```
-- Create trigger to not throw in case of duplicate mapping attempt
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.BlockDuplicates_Product_Category_Mapping
ON dbo.Product_Category_Mapping
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM inserted AS i 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.Product_Category_Mapping AS p
                            ON i.ProductId = p.ProductId
                            AND i.CategoryId = p.CategoryId)
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.Product_Category_Mapping (ProductId, CategoryId, IsFeaturedProduct, DisplayOrder)
          SELECT ProductId, CategoryId, IsFeaturedProduct, DisplayOrder 
          FROM inserted;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'Duplicate';
  END
END
```

And it works fine if I run it directly from my DBMS:

[image]

But, if I use it in code with EF:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.15" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.15" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.15" />
```

It doesn't seem to work, a duplicate key exception is thrown, which is what I was trying to avoid:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_PCM_ProductId_CategoryId'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Product_Category_Mapping'. The duplicate key value is (920, 129).

This is being inserted through a navigation property, if it makes any difference.

Can someone point out to me why this is not working?

I followed these two related questions but I don't see nothing that can help:

[SQL Server 2008 insert trigger not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5555492/6865932)

[SQL Server 2008 - insert trigger not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35002410/6865932)

Comment: Why use a trigger for this at all? Why do you want to *hide* the error from the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`? This smells like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: @ThomA it has a unique constraint, but I don't want it to cause an error, just want to print out the 'Duplicate' text, as shown in the image and move on.

Comment: Then, in your application, handle the error code there. Don't smother it in your trigger.

Comment: @ThomA that would be what I'd do, but this is a db that serves other apps and it wasn't a unique constraint before, it was added recently, so I don't want to break code to which I have no access to, it's stupid, I agree, but it's what I have in my hands.

Comment: I would, personally, suggest that smothering the error and giving those other applications the *impression* everything worked, when it fact nothing happened, is a much bigger problem than having them generate an error that tells the user that what they tried to do didn't work.

Comment: @ThomA, it makes retro compatible, if someone tries to add this key it doesn't add nothing, but there's no problem because it already exists, no harm no foul.

Comment: It will just have unexpected values values for IsFeaturedProduct, DisplayOrder after such a no op insert. That does sound harmful to me.

Comment: Your trigger code is pretty bad, since if 1 out of 5 rows exist, it still inserts everything. This is a sure sign that things have gone wrong. I won't mention locking issues. Also, you might still have duplicates in the inserted table

Comment: @Ralf good point and it was raised, but it is not a problem.

Comment: You might have a typical timing issue here. You check then change. Between check and change someone else might have changed data without proper locking/transaction behavior.

Comment: It *is* a problem if, for example, they wanted to add that product as a featured product, and it wasn't in the data already, @anastaciu , or they want it in a different display order. *If* you were just inserted the values of the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, and those were the only values in the table, I'd accept that reasoning, however, you are not.

Comment: You probably have more luck removing constraint again and delete duplicates in the trigger itself

Comment: @ThomA, as I told Ralf, this was raised, and was deemed to not be a problem, those values are edited after the fact, in fact the default insert values are 0 0.

Comment: @siggemannen there's an idea, thanks for the input. I don't have duplicates because I had to remove them when I added the unique constraint.

Comment: All that said (and valid), there's no way for EF to bypass a trigger. Are you sure you had the same insert statement and didn't run into the issue Siggemann pointed out above?

Comment: @GertArnold the insert statement had 2 duplicate rows, there were no new inserts in my test scenario. No new ones were being added.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm not the shapest tool in the shed when it comes to SQL, still, I used the trigger in the answer bellow, it works in the dbms but same thing happens with EF core, Duplicate key exception.

Comment: Seems like you've found your crystal ball, @siggemannen .

Comment: @ThomA yeah, but i kinda messed it up because i wrote inserted table, and OP thought i ment `Product_Category_Mapping` and not `inserted`:)

Comment: Yeah, admittedly that's how initially read it too, @siggemannen .

Comment: @siggemannen Just to acknowledge you were absolutely right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to bang the drum again: This idea is a *bad* idea. Giving the impression to an application/user that things "worked" when they didn't is not a good idea. In this case you say it's "not a problem" but I would say with confidence that at some point a user is going to ask "Why is the product I added just now not featured, when I asked it to be." and the answer will be "Your `INSERT` was ignored, but we smothered that error for you and didn't tell you."

That being said, you're going about this the wrong way if you "must" (***don't***) do this in a trigger. If you're inserting multiple rows this is going to go all sorts of wrong, as if even 1 of those rows is a duplicate you ignore ***all of them***. Inserting 100 new products, and 1 is a dupe? You insert **zero**.

Instead, use a `INSERT` with a `NOT EXISTS` and "bin" the rest. Not ideal, and your users will be confused, but this appears to be the behaviour you are after, at least:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.BlockDuplicates_Product_Category_Mapping
ON dbo.Product_Category_Mapping
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Product_Category_Mapping (ProductId,
                                              CategoryId,
                                              IsFeaturedProduct,
                                              DisplayOrder)
    SELECT i.ProductId,
           i.CategoryId,
           i.IsFeaturedProduct,
           i.DisplayOrder
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.Product_Category_Mapping PCM
                      WHERE PCM.ProductId = i.ProductId
                        AND PCM.CategoryId = i.CategoryId);
END;
```

If you *really* wanted to be nice to your users (to avoid their confusion when things aren't inserted), you could do an Upsert. Then you `UPDATE` the rows that already existed, to the values they wanted to `INSERT`, and `INSERT` the new ones.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.BlockDuplicates_Product_Category_Mapping
ON dbo.Product_Category_Mapping
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --No need to define a transaction, as a trigger is already inside one and automatically has XACT_ABORT enabled

    UPDATE PCM
    SET IsFeaturedProduct = i.IsFeaturedProduct,
        DisplayOrder = i.DisplayOrder
    FROM dbo.Product_Category_Mapping PCM WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
        JOIN inserted i ON PCM.ProductId = i.ProductId
                       AND PCM.CategoryId = i.CategoryId;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Product_Category_Mapping (ProductId,
                                              CategoryId,
                                              IsFeaturedProduct,
                                              DisplayOrder)
    SELECT i.ProductId,
           i.CategoryId,
           i.IsFeaturedProduct,
           i.DisplayOrder
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.Product_Category_Mapping PCM
                      WHERE PCM.ProductId = i.ProductId
                        AND PCM.CategoryId = i.CategoryId);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second, which is great, a definite upgrade, I found a bug though, it was inserting 2 equal rows in the same transaction, which was still failing even with your improved code, I guess its a very corner, corner case. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the data you are passing has 2 or more rows with the *same* values, @anastaciu . That will cause the error. Something like `INSERT INTO dbo.Product_Category_Mapping (ProductID, CategoryId) VALUES (1,2),(1,2);` That wouldn't be a trigger issue, that's an input issue. Fixing the application to not allow that would be the requirement there (but you've already stated there's not appetite to fix that application(s)).

Comment: Yes, that was it.

Comment: So the trigger wasn't be ignored. You *could* handle this in the trigger too, @anastaciu , but you'd have to know which row is the correct row when you're inserting it twice. But, to bang that drum again: fix the applications.

Comment: Yes, preaching to the choir my friend, thanks again.